# java nested JSONArray

Tags: java, json, parsing, arrays

I want to know if it is possible to check if some key exists in some jsonArray using java. For example: lets say that I have this json string:

```
{'abc':'hello','xyz':[{'name':'Moses'}]}
```

let's assume that this array is stored in jsnArray from Type `JSONArray`.
I want to check if 'abc' key exists in the jsnArray, if it exists I should get `true` else I should get `false` (in the case of 'abc' I should get true). 
Thnkas

Comment: This is not a valid json array. Either you mean `{'abc':'hello','xyz':[{'name':'Moses'}]}` or `[{'abc':'hello'}, {'xyz':[{'name':'Moses'}}]`?

Comment: I will change it, thanks. still how I do what I've asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted is a `JSONObject`, inside which there is a `JSONArray`. The only array you have in this example is the array `'xyz'`, that contains only one element.

A JSONArray example is the following one:

```
{
 'jArray':
          [
           {'hello':'world'},
           {'name':'Moses'},
           ...
           {'thisIs':'theLast'}
          ]
}
```

You can test if a `JSONArray` called `jArray`, included inside a given `JSONObject` (a situation similar to the example above) contains the key 'hello' with the following function:

```
boolean containsKey(JSONObject myJsonObject, String key) {
    boolean containsHelloKey = false;
    try {
        JSONArray arr = myJsonObject.getJSONArray("jArray");
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); ++i) {
            if(arr.getJSONObject(i).get(key) != null) {
               containsHelloKey = true;
               break;
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {}

    return containsHelloKey;
}
```

And calling that in this way:

```
containsKey(myJsonObject, "hello");
```

Comment: i think it soulde be with try/ catch

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions will not work because of the opening and closing brackets.

You could use a JSON library (like [google-gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)) to transform your JSON Array into a java array and then handle it.

Answer (score 1):

JSON arrays don't have key value pairs, JSON objects do.

If you store it as a json object you can check the keys using this method:
http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

Comment: is there any why to convert jsonarray to json object?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply parse the input as a JSONObject in the first place? From your syntax above, it looks like you're receiving a JSONObject anyway, so you shouldn't be able to save it as a JSONArray in the first place.

Comment: I am using Parse as my cloude database. and I want to store this "complex" json array in one of the fields. Maybe it is better to store the json as a string in the Parse db?

Comment: I don't know much about parse sorry, but yes a string should also work. 

It seems to me if parse is capable of returning a json array it should be capable of returning a json object? Alternatively you could wrap your object in an array, like:
[{'abc':'hello','xyz':[{'name':'Moses'}]}]
then get the first item in that array as a jsonObject:
JSONObject myJSONObject = myJSONArray.get(0)

Answer (score 1):

If you use JSON Smart Library in Java to parse JSon String -

You can parse JSon Array with following code snippet -

like -

```
JSONObject resultsJSONObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(<<Fetched JSon String>>);
JSONArray dataJSon = (JSONArray) resultsJSONObject.get("data");
JSONObject[] updates = dataJSon.toArray(new JSONObject[dataJSon.size()]);

for (JSONObject update : updates) {
            String message_id = (String) update.get("message_id");
            Integer author_id = (Integer) update.get("author_id");
            Integer createdTime = (Integer) update.get("created_time");
            //Do your own processing...
            //Here you can check null value or not..
}
```

You can have more information in - https://code.google.com/p/json-smart/

Hope this help you...